# How many times vehicle passes on same route

Tags: here-maps-rest, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk, heremaps-ios-sdk, heremap-navigation

Can we define how many times vehicle should pass on a same route?
Basically we need an API in here maps where we can configure/define how many times a vehicle should pass on a same route?

Comment: Are you wanting to do this in voice guided navigation, or count passes on historical GPS traces? For voice guided navigation you can add hundreds of "via waypoints" that guide the route. If you need the route to be specifically followed you can turn off traffic re-route.

Comment: @CSchwarz - We want to define a custom route in here maps, along with 'N' number of pass through on that custom route and will share that route to the driver. So that driver should be able to navigate through that custom route.

Answer (score 1):

You can set "passthrough" via waypoints:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/waypoint.html
These allow you to direct the route.
I have succesfully set 1500+ passthrough waypoints in iOS, and hundreds via the javascript api (approx 250 as GET parameters). Experiment with your own maximum if you need many waypoints.
Note that if you don't set the waypoints as "passthrough" they are stopover waypoints and will be announced during voice guided navigation.

Here is a video showing multiple passes of the same locations in one voice guided navigation session: https://youtu.be/j8rFZAdqBkk

Comment: Our requirement is the vehicle should pass N times via custom route(via specifies the way points)?

Comment: I understand your query now, the issue is will a "via waypoint" be considered as passed the first time it has been driven along and be removed from the route. That requires testing. I may report back soon.

Comment: Yes it is possible to continue past the same locations multiple times. I have added a video showing that happen with the current Here routing api

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick turnaround. We were looking something like this.
 
Can you please share the API details so that we can draw custom route like you did and pass through that multiple times?

I am also looking for, is there anyway to export(KML/KMZ format) this custom route and share with my friends and they should be able to navigate (turn by turn) through it?

Comment: I used the iOS SDK for the voice guided navigation application: https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-sdk-navigate/4.10.4.0/dev_guide/index.html and the Here Maps API for Javascript for the webpage to create and save the route: https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.30.9/dev_guide/index.html I use my own backend to store the route and send it to the iOS application

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will get in touch with you for more details.